# Woocommerce Create Coupons in WordPress Core

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This maybe a daft question, but I couldn't find the answer (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789786/programatically-create-multiple-coupons-in-woocommerce) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744689/how-do-i-programmatically-apply-a-coupon-in-woocommerce) for related/unanswered questions)

**What I am trying to do:**

I would like to programmatically make coupons for use by Woocommerce and found the reference code here: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/create-a-coupon-programatically/

But how to actually hook this up to the WordPress core so that they are created?

Is there a specific WordPress file or files that I need to include so that I can run these actions?

**Note:** This is for standalone code so that I can add more when I need to.

Comment: woocommerce have the defoult functionality  avaiable  to create coupon

Comment: Hi Vickey, yes the code is above, I want to add a coupon in standalone code (so I can bring lots in via a CSV file for example)

Comment: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/smart-coupons/

Comment: Hi Vickey, that's not what I'm after. Those are available coupons and not adding coupons programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who was struggling with this too, add this to your PHP code:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
global $wp, $wp_query, $wp_the_query, $wp_rewrite, $wp_did_header;
require('../wp-load.php');
```

Then you can hijack the WordPress code and create coupons, yay!

Matt